# Sort KnockoutJS observable array element dynamically

Tags: knockout.js

Suppose my observable array contains a list of tags with property selected:

```
myModel = {
 tags: ko.observableArray([
   {name: "tag1", selected: ko.observable()},
   {name: "tag2", selected: ko.observable(true)},
   ...
 ])
}
```

Now I want the tags array sort dynamically based on the `selected()` attribute, say if a tag is selected, then it should be move to the top of the list.

Any idea how to get this done?

Answer (score 1):

You could easily use a computed here to make sure when selected changes you re-sort -

```
var alphabeticalOrderSort = function (l, r) { return (l.selected() == r.selected()) ? (l.selected() > r.selected() ? 1 : -1) : (l.selected() > r.selected() ? 1 : -1) };

computedTags: ko.computed(function () {
    return tags().sort(sortFunction);
})
```

You will need to test out your own sort function to work how you want it but now if you bind your view to the computedTags it will always sort when selected changes.